# how to delay current date by 5 hrs in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery

Please find my script below ..
http://jsfiddle.net/ramu_steve/Fcbjr/1/

i am displaying the current date in date field as you see in the above script .. so i need to display the current date by delaying 5 hrs .. example.. if user select the form at 12:30AM or 5:00AM on 07/18/2012 .. it has to display 07/17/2012 ..so the date has to be changed only after 5:00AM..is it possible to delay the current date by 5 hrs?. thanks in advance ...

thanks every one and here is my solution with updated script

http://jsfiddle.net/ramu_steve/Fcbjr/3/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do the time logic to determine the date to display before setting the date.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aztechy/25K4C/

This is a very basic example.  As I understand it, anything before 5am should use the date prior, otherwise, the date displayed is the current date.

You can play around with the logic by clearly defining the date parameters when creating var currentDate as such:

```
var currentDate = new Date(year, month, day, hour); // Filling in the proper numerical values for the variable placeholders of course.
```

Comment: could you please provide me with an example .. thanks in advance

Comment: Great, glad it helped out.  Please accept the answer if you could :).